# update rows in a single table based on join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Query that produces rows that I wish to update, and the query looks like this:

```
SELECT item.item_id
FROM   items
JOIN   users2items
ON     users2items.item_id = items.item_id
WHERE  users2items.user_id = 10;
```

Now I need to update a column for each record that matches that query in the item table; currently I'm taking the result set and then building and executing queries for each result, but I figure there is probably a way to do this directly in SQL. The individual statements I'm executing are:

```
UPDATE items SET is_usable = 1 WHERE item_id = $current_id
```

So it works as is, but I'm trying to learn if there's a pure-SQL way to do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE items
JOIN   users2items
ON     users2items.item_id = items.item_id
SET    is_usable = 1
WHERE  users2items.user_id = 10
```

Comment: I feel stupid now - I'd tried this and it had failed, but apparently through a typo I'd made at the time.

Comment: Why do you think this site was so popular in the first place!